# Layout multiple invoices and printing issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on asp.net project where i need to layout multiple selected invoices on single page. once click on print button will print all invoices but each invoice should be printed on separate page.

Is is possible in asp.net or need manual adjustments in layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, but you need to do it with CSS using `@media print`.

Define a class like so:

```
@media print
{
  .page-break  { display:block; page-break-before:always; }
}

@media all
{
  .page-break  { display:none; }
}
```

And simply add `<div class="page-break"></div>` between every invoice you want to print on a separate page.